# after successfully provisioning prometheus server on ec2, the server comes up with connection refused when tried to open from web brower

Tags: terraform, prometheus, terraform-provider-aws

i provisioned a prometheus server on an ec2 instance with terraform. the scrip ran successfully and the server created. but when i tried to open it from web browser it gives connection refused.

i tried running the the commands/scrip directly by ssh-ing to a test server from cli , it ran successfully and also opened from web browser. after successfully creating the prometheus server its expected to be accessible from web browser when http://server-IP-or-Hostname:9090.

1. ## prometheus provision

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {

    inline = [
      "sudo useradd --no-create-home --shell /bin/false prometheus",
      "sudo mkdir /etc/prometheus",
      "sudo mkdir /var/lib/prometheus",
      "sudo chown -R prometheus. /etc/prometheus",
      "sudo chown -R prometheus. /var/lib/prometheus",
      "cd ~",
      

      "wget  https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v2.41.0/prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz" ,
      "tar -xvf prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz" ,
      "sudo cp prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64/prometheus /usr/local/bin/",
      "sudo cp prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64/promtool /usr/local/bin/",
      "sudo chown prometheus. /usr/local/bin/prometheus",
      "sudo chown prometheus. /usr/local/bin/promtool",
      "sudo cp -r prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64/consoles /etc/prometheus",
      "sudo cp -r prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64/console_libraries /etc/prometheus",

      "rm -rf prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64.tar.gz prometheus-2.41.0.linux-amd64" ,
      "sudo cp prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
      "sudo chown prometheus. /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
      "sudo cp prometheus.service  /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service" ,

      "sudo chown prometheus:prometheus /etc/prometheus" ,
      "sudo chown prometheus:prometheus /usr/local/bin/prometheus" ,
      "sudo chown prometheus:prometheus /usr/local/bin/promtool" ,
      "sudo chown -R prometheus:prometheus /etc/prometheus/consoles" ,
      "sudo chown -R prometheus:prometheus /etc/prometheus/console_libraries" ,
      "sudo chown -R prometheus:prometheus /var/lib/prometheus" ,

      "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" ,
      "sudo systemctl enable prometheus" ,
      "sudo systemctl start prometheus" ,
      


    ]
  }
```

Comment: Honestly, I would say this is not the best terraform used case. Nevertheless, did you check your security group associated with the EC2 instance, does it allow the inbound rule for port 9090? And the ec2 instance running with public IP?

Comment: yes i did, thase where the first things i checked